# meaning of "lost" in "All is not lost"

Tags: idioms, proverbs

I'd like to know if "All is not lost" is an idiom or a proverb. Also, what does "lost" mean literally here?

I know the meaning of this saying. I just want to see if the meaning of this saying is deducible from the meaning of its component words.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes, its meaning can be deduced from the words.  You can lose your car keys. You can be lost at sea.  You can lose a battle. The battle can be lost.  "It is not a total defeat" would be a decent paraphrase.

Comment: What exactly described is not "lost" in "All is not lost"?

Comment: I don't see the connection between the literal sense of "lost" (as in "lost a key") and the actual interpretation of "All is not lost."

Comment: It seems "lost" as in "All is not lost" means "hopeless," and has the same meaning as "lost" as in "a lost cause." But would you say a lost cause is a cause that has been lost?

Comment: A **cause** and a **battle** are analogues. It's a figurative usage, not an idiom, and not a proverb.  I cannot help it if you don't see the connection.  A **lost cause** has become a separate collocation.  You may be a lost cause if there's no getting you to change your ways.

Comment: Maybe that sense is also found in "Her advice was lost on me" and "The lecture was lost on us"?

Comment: You're losing me.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Macmillan's dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/all-is-not-lost), 'All is not lost' is neither a proverb nor an idiom. It's a phrase of 'lost'.

The meaning of this phrase is:

> Still some chance of success or recovery.

Now, the verb 'lose' has many meanings as you can check [here](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/lose). But, for this particular phrase, we can say that someone has a little hope for recovery or success is still left.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Oxford Dictionaries:

> [All is not lost](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/all_is_not_lost)
>
> is used to suggest that there is still some chance of success or recovery:
>
> I know things look grim, but all is not lost

In other words there are still chances of improving the situation we're in.

Comment: I know the meaning of this saying. All I'm doing is trying to see if its meaning can be deduced from the meanings of its components.

Comment: Yes, you can get its meaning. Not all (everything) is lost. @Apollyon

Comment: It seems "lost" as in "All is not lost" means "hopeless," and has the same meaning as "lost" as in "a lost cause." But would you say a lost cause is a cause that has been lost?